# Use special characters in enum in solidity

Tags: solidity

Does someone knows how to use special characters in enum in solidity? Something like

```
enum TipoMonstro{
    Raro,
    Enganação
}
```

It does not compile due to the "çã". The solidity documentation wasn't helpful at this point. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *All identifiers (contract names, function names and variable names) are restricted to the ASCII character set. It is possible to store UTF-8 encoded data in string variables.*

Source: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html

So you can only use ASCII characters as the enum identifier.

---

It's generally a good practice to use only english variable names (i.e. ASCII charset), so that you don't run into issues with encoding. Even though the programming language might support other encodings as well, your colleague's IDE might not, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on the solidity version you are using. Please, check this post. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/97173/do-solidity-smart-contract-symbols-support-unicode/97174

Comment: I already tried, it works well for strings but not for enums. I think It can't be done for enums, but maybe I am wrong.